# Are 'Functional Indexes' Supported in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, index, functions

I've just come across [expression based indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) (aka "functional indexes") when reading through the documentation for PostgreSQL (I wasn't aware of such indexes previously).

I'm just wondering if there is anything that is similar/equivalent to this in Microsoft SQL Server? I have read the [SQL Server documentation on indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) and I don't see anything that is obviously similar/equivalent.

Answer (score 14):

While there isn't a feature of Functional Indexes in SQL Server per se, one can mimic a *similar* implementation via [indexing on top of a Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns?view=sql-server-ver15). Computed columns allow functions to be utilized. They also can even be persisted such that the result of a function is stored in the column on disk (as opposed to being evaluated every time at query runtime).

So long as the requirements of the document I linked above are met, it's possible to index on top of a function result similar to Functional Indexes from PostgreSQL. One of the most important requirements is that the function is a [**deterministic function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver15), meaning it outputs the same result for the same input always. For example, `ISNULL()` is deterministic because the same input parameter will always return the same outputted result. But the `GETDATE()` function is **nondeterministic** because the same input (which happens to be no input for this particular function) always results in a different outputted result, one day to the next, when it's called.

Answer (score 9):

The closest equivalent is that you can create a computed column and then index that column.

Computed column matching is a bit hit and miss but generally SQL Server will match the function call to the matching index.

```
CREATE TABLE #Demo
(
Foo VARCHAR(50)
)

ALTER TABLE #Demo ADD LowerFoo AS lower(Foo)

CREATE INDEX IX ON #Demo(LowerFoo)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #Demo 
WHERE lower(Foo) = 'aa'
```

[image]

Comment: Is this supported in AzureSQL ?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to indexes on computed columns, you sometimes use [Indexed Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) instead.  Computed columns change the logical design of the table, and sometimes that's not desirable or possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could emulate functional indexes via computed columns:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns

There are few restrictions:

- All functions that are referenced by the expression are deterministic and precise.
- All columns that are referenced in the expression come from the table that contains the computed column.
- No column reference pulls data from multiple rows.
- The computed_column_expression has no system data access or user data access.
- The computed_column_expression defined for the computed column can't evaluate to the `text`, `ntext`, or `image` data types.

Additionally:

- You can't create a filtered index on a computed column.

Such a column is leaky - non-portable.

For my use case I needed a unique index - only one row could be `status = 'ACTIVE'`, so an extra functional column is not a problem for me, it is invisible for the app and is only for *integrity enforcement*:

```
-- NULLs are not duplication for UNIQUE INDEX!
ALTER TABLE pricing_upload ADD latest AS (CASE WHEN status ='ACTIVE' THEN 'Y' END);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pricing_upload_latest_un
ON pricing_upload(latest);
```

Answer (score -1):

The main difference between PostGreSQL and MS SQL Server is that MS SQL Server supports functional indexes since almost 21 years through the concept of indexed computed columns....

But in addition, SQL Server publish the value of the column in the table definition.

And now you have fours ways of creating such a fonctionnality :

1. Computed columns without any storage called unpersisted computed
   columns
2. Computed columns with storage called persisted computed columns
3. Computed columns with index storage only called indexed computed
   columns
4. Computed columns with value and index storage called persisted
   computed columns

PostGreSQL does not have such equivalent and only give the possibility to create indexed computed columns without any way to view the value in a column...

By the way, computed columns without any storage that are called unpersisted computed columns is a functionnal equivalent to what you can do with a view.

The only difference is that you must have the computed column into the table in MS SQL Server... that PG do not have !

Comment: Your answer is not up to date. Postgres implemented generated columns in version 12. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250729/939860